# Understanding the weights of a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, weights, batch-normalization

I've been working with an **artificial neural network** in Torch, to solve a binary classification problem.
I've had several troubles by using the **mini-batch** gradient update.

Each element of my dataset can be -1 (false) or +1 (true).
I cannot explain why, but my mini-batch execution tests produce sufficient results (Matthews correlation coefficient in the test set around +0.30) if the percentage of negative elements in the training set is **49%**.
On the contrary, if it is **50%** or greater, the neural network will produce only ones as output, and if it's lower than 49%, the neural network will produce only zeros as output.
In all the cases I'm using a mini-batch size of 20.

I decided to take a look to the neural network weights, after training.
This is the heatmap of the weights of my input layer neurons (82x100) for my 49% case:

[image]

And this is the heatmap of the weights of my input layer neurons (82x100) for my 50% case:

[image]

As you can see, the first one looks more stable: almost all the values are around 0, and the extremes are very few.
On the contrary, the second one looks quite "crazy", with apparently random values always extremes around -1 and +1.

**What are these images telling me?**

**Is there some addition information I can get from these images?**

**Why does the second image look so polarized towards the extreme values?**

Comment: Pls explain "percentage of negative elements in the training set is 49%". Is this a binary classification problem where you're trying to predict class 0 and 1?

Comment: @horaceT Yes, classification

Comment: It sounds like your units might be saturating (certainly of the output unit). Can you check for hidden layers? Also, what kind of nonlinearity are you using in the hidden layer?

Comment: A similar visualization has been made in this [lecture notes](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jdomke/courses/sml2010/07autodiff_nnets.pdf) page 7. It is easier to understand there, because it is a vision problem in MNIST data. In your case, hard to say be cause your data may not has visual explanations.